# First moderator flag declined

Tags: support

I raised a custom mod flag with this text:

> A-ing~♡

This means in Korean:

> 아잉~♡

But it was declined:

> [image]

Why is this not a "valid flag"?  Why did the mods decline me to act cute/aegyo here?

Comment: Normally the flag is used to point out if there is any problem with the post. Was there any problem? What did you expect to happen if the flag hadn't been declined?

Comment: Why can't I try to act cute here?

Comment: you can, but this is what will happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Remember these?

> **[What makes a good use of the phrase “Nico-nico-nii” here?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/554/6567)**
>
> **[Why is “Nico-nico-nii” not allowed on Stack Exchange?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/533/6567)**
>
> **[Why were my two answers deleted?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3208/37992)**

*All of these questions were asked by you, User Yubin-chan (formerly Maika Sakuranomiya), before you deleted your account on* MusicFans *and* Music: Practice and Theory *following multiple suspensions on both sites for similar misbehavior.*

*Your [profiles](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2563/yubin-chan) on all your SE accounts specifically mention mod flags, showing an image of a moderator flag that you raised that was rejected:*

> [image: Yubin-chan's profile]

### I see no reason why you should not already be intimately aware of the regulations on moderator flags.

Comment: Because it is a different phrase.  I didn't even write "nico nico nii" there.

Comment: Oh, [what a terrible and horrific idea](https://upload.inven.co.kr/upload/2014/12/23/bbs/i3324974586.jpg) to use nico-nico-nii as a comment of a flag?